# Working with convergence in normed vector spaces (and understanding it)

Tags: functional-analysis

I am learning about sequence spaces. To understand convergence in normed vector spaces I tried to do the following exercise

Does the sequence $e:=(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $e_n$ is the n-th unit vector, converge in the space $c_0 $

First, I wrote down the definitions:

Definition (convergence in a normed vector space):
Let $(X, \lVert \rVert)$ be a normed vector space.
A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent in $(X, \lVert \rVert)$ if $\lVert x_n -x \rVert < \epsilon$  for all n > $N$
where $x_n,x \in X$

$c_0:= \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: \lim x_n =0 \}$ with the norm $||x||:=sup|x_k|$

My attempt:
As far as I understand $(e_n)_n$ is the sequence

$\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ .\\ .\\ \end{array} \right)$,$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\\ .\\ .\\ \end{array} \right)$,$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ .\\ .\\ \end{array} \right)$,...

For $(e_n)_n$ to converge to $x \in c_0$ means that $\lVert e_n-x\rVert < \epsilon$

Now, looking at this I can't say if there exists such an $x \in c_0$.
My only approach would be to write $\lVert e_n-x\rVert $ and use how the norm is defined in $c_0$. This means $\lVert e_n-x\rVert =\underset{n \in \mathbb{N}}{sup}|e_n-x|$

I know that $sup|x|=c \in \mathbb{R}$ , and $sup|e_n|=1 $

But I don't really know how to continue from here on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Normed vector spaces are, in particular, metric spaces. If a sequence converges, it *must* be a Cauchy sequence (exercise + note the converse if true iff. the space is a Banach space). But what is $\|e_n-e_m\|$ when $n\neq m$?

Norm convergence, or *strong* convergence, "works" just like convergence in $\Bbb R$. Indeed $\Bbb R$ is a Banach space, so everything there is a special case. Convergence in vector spaces gets 'weird' once you look at things like weak and weak-$\ast$ convergence.

Comment: This means, since $\rVert e_n - e_m \lVert=1$, $(e_n)_n$ is not cauchy and because $c_0$ is a banach space, it follows that $(e_n)_n$ does not converge in $c_0$. Is this correct?

Comment: @wanymose Almost. $c_0$ being a Banach space would only be relevant to the *converse*, i.e. "if ... is Cauchy, then it converges". But in any normed (metric) space whatsoever, convergence implies it is Cauchy

Comment: Ok thanks, I did mix that up. So, if $(e_n)_n$ is convergent, it would follow that it is cauchy. Assumin $(e_n)_n$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $(e_n)_n$ is cauchy, but that is a contradiction

Comment: @wanymose That's right. Because if $\|e_n-x\|$ is small for large $n$, then $\|e_n-e_m\|=\|(e_n-x)-(e_m-x)\|\le\|e_n-x\|+\|e_m-x\|$ is small when $n,m$ are large - which is very false

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The notion of Cauchy sequences is not necessary here. Use more directly the fact that uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence:

$\lVert e_n-x\rVert$ is not equal to "$\underset{n \in \mathbb{N}}{sup}|e_n-x|$", which means nothing, but to
$$\sup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}|e_n(k)-x(k)|.$$
Now as $n\to\infty,$ if $e_n\to x,$ i.e. if this sup tends to $0$ then
$$\forall k\in\Bbb N\quad x_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n(k)=0,$$
i.e. $x$ is the zero sequence, whose norm is $0.$

But this is impossible, since $\|e_n\|=1\not\to0.$

Note that $c_0$ is a subspace of the space $\ell^\infty$ of bounded sequences (also equipped with the sup norm) and $(e_n)$ does not converge either in $\ell^\infty,$ by the same proof (or as a corollary, if you know that $c_0$ is closed in $\ell^\infty$).

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to understand it better. Especially the mention of $\lVert e_n-x \rVert = \underset{k \in \mathbb{N}}{sup}|e_n(k)-x(k)|$

Comment: Just because of curiosity, a question: Would $(e_n)_n$ converge in for example $l^1$? Because I did some thinking: $\lVert e_n-x \rVert=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |e_n(k) -x(k)|$ 

If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |e_n(k) -x(k)|< \epsilon$ $\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |e_n(k) -x(k)|=0$, since the absolute value is $\geq 0$  $\Rightarrow e_n(k)=x(k)$. Now if $n \rightarrow \infty$ $x(k)=0$, and by $\lVert e_n \rVert =1$. So it does not converge in $l^1$

Comment: [Well done!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4080883).

Comment: Thank you very much!